# Android onTouch with onClick and onLongClick

Tags: android, click, touch

I've got a custom view which acts like a button. I want to change the background when user press it, revert the background to original when user moves the finger outside or release it and I also want to handle onClick/onLongClick events. The problem is that onTouch requires me to return true for `ACTION_DOWN` or it won't send me the `ACTION_UP` event. But if I return true the `onClick` listener won't work.

I thought I solved it by returning false in onTouch and registering onClick - it somehow worked, but was kinda against the docs. I've just received a message from an user telling me that he's not able to long-click on the button, so I'm wondering what's wrong here.

Part of the current code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt)
{
  switch (evt.getAction())
  {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
      setSelection(true); // it just change the background
      break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
    {
      setSelection(false); // it just change the background
      break;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
  // some other code here
}

public boolean onLongClick(View view)
  {
    // just showing a Toast here
    return false;
  }


// somewhere else in code
setOnTouchListener(this);
setOnClickListener(this);
setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

How do I make them work together correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`onClick` & `onLongClick` is actually dispatched from `View.onTouchEvent`.

if you override `View.onTouchEvent` or set some specific `View.OnTouchListener` via `setOnTouchListener`,
you must care for that.

so your code should be something like:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt)
{
  // to dispatch click / long click event,
  // you must pass the event to it's default callback View.onTouchEvent
  boolean defaultResult = v.onTouchEvent(evt);

  switch (evt.getAction())
  {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
      setSelection(true); // just changing the background
      break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
    {
      setSelection(false); // just changing the background
      break;
    }
    default:
      return defaultResult;
  }

  // if you reach here, you have consumed the event
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @ranasaha Handling this event is complecated. Check all your code which relates to touch event. Just reporting `Doesent work` will not help your problem. Re-consider why it doesn't work before posting poor reports on the incident to me.