# touch listener and long click listener

Tags: android, object, position, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

i wrote a code with touch listener on surface view to  move object and it work great,  when i insert on long click listener the touch listener stop working well and the object move even if i not touch it. the long clickneed to open dialog.

on create:

```
sf = new SurfaceView(this);
sf.setOnTouchListener(this);
sf.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

on Long Click:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (!changePositionMode){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.text_manager);
        dialog.setTitle("Browser");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

on touch listener

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Point p=new Point((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        }else if (object.isTouch(p)){
            changePositionMode=true;
            x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();
            draw();
            return true;
        }   
    }
    else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        t.changeTamplatePosition(event.getX()-x,event.getY()-y);
        x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();
        draw();
        return true;
    }
    else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        changePositionMode=false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Refer to this answer for how to pass the touch event to the longClickListener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387572/android-ontouch-with-onclick-and-onlongclick

Comment: long click well ? the problem is on the touch event?

Comment: the problem is on touch event

Answer (score 5):

You have to return `false` instead of `true` in `OnTouch(View v,MotionEvent event)` function so that other listeners(OnLongClickListener) on the control remains active.